# FaceDetector.findFaces accuracy params

Tags: android, face-detection

I have been implementing the FaceDetector.findFaces() feature in my app to find/recognize faces in a selected Bitmap and I see that it works only for 100% clear faces.

Is there a way to apply a kind of 'accuracy' params so that a partial visible face is still accepted?

In my app I want to restrict profile pictures selection only to the ones showing the face and the code is plain simple:

```
private boolean faceIsDetected(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap image2 = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, false);

        FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector(image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight(), 5);
        if (faceDetector.findFaces(image2, new FaceDetector.Face[5]) > 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

The generated bitmap and see that it follows the requirements: it is RGB_565 and it has an even width.

Answer (score 0):

The object [`Face`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face) includes already a `confidence()` value. From the documentation:

> Returns a confidence factor between 0 and 1. This indicates how
> certain what has been found is actually a face. A confidence factor
> above 0.3 is usually good enough.

You would need to define your minimum value for this field, and decide when is good enough for you.

There is also a [`CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face#CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD) constant that defines the minimum confidence factor of good face recognition (which is 0.4F).

In my experiments this value typically oscillates between 0.5 and 0.53, and I never had anything outside that range. You are probably better off using [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android).